# Programmatically launch a web app on the home screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, homescreen, iphone-web-app, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have an enterprise application that has a web app added to the Home Screen of the iPad. I want to be able to launch the web app from my native XCode app. Is this possible?

Can a web app have an associated custom protocol registered?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Custom URLs open other native apps. If you want to open a web app, you can simply pass the http:// URL, however, doing so will load the standard Safari browser rather than a new instance of webkit that you would get with tapping the web clip in the home screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was specifically asking for a solution to launch home screen webapps.

Comment: Sorry. I guess I should have been more explicit. The answer to your question is no. There is no way to register a custom URL that will open your webclip (web app icon in home screen) from another app. Here's a similar question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194578/force-url-to-open-in-a-web-clip-if-installed . The only way to open a web app is the way I've described. Best regards and good luck.