# Scheme to link back to a web application?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I would like to use a [Web Application](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW3) on an iPad. It servers as a launcher for PayPal Here app via `paypalhere://takePayment` scheme, which receives a payment through a card reader, and then, after a successful payment, should return back to the app, with some `GET` parameters.

Is there a scheme (or a way to register it) which would switch back to the Web App?

If I didn't use the Web App, the workflow would have one extra step - a pop-up with "Open in PayPal Here?" question, plus, the return URL would open a new tab anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can try [url scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app?language=objc)

Comment: Its not possible to link back to a web application from a webapp.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256053/programmatically-launch-a-web-app-on-the-home-screen

Comment: Thank you @TibinThomas, pity it wasn't an answer, the bounty would go to you...

Comment: Thanks @JosefHabr for the update.I will update the comment into an answer for better clarity,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.It is not possible** to link back to a web app from a native iOS application using *url schemes*.

*URL schemes* are meant for native applications to open other native applications.For this capability the application has to register the url schemes it support via *info.plist* file.Web apps are currently not capable of doing so and hence doesn't support url schemes.*It may be supported in the future* in PWA's as apple is adopting PWA's into iOS.Refer this [Open installed PWA from external url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929198/open-installed-pwa-from-external-url)
 and[this medium article](https://medium.com/@firt/progressive-web-apps-on-ios-are-here-d00430dee3a7)

Although you can open the webpage from a native app using *openUrl* method it would be opening in safari instead of as a web application.

Reference:[Programmatically launch a web app on the home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256053/programmatically-launch-a-web-app-on-the-home-screen)

Comment: Thank you for this heads-up, PWA looks interesting, hope Apple will adopt it, I do feel it could be as easy as adding a meta tag in the app with the link (although not sure what a conflict with another app could do).

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @TibinThomas, I know now it's **not** possible. These are two good resources.

- [Programmatically launch a web app on the home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256053/programmatically-launch-a-web-app-on-the-home-screen)
- [Force URL to open in a Web Clip if installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194578/force-url-to-open-in-a-web-clip-if-installed)

I guess I will first base the workflow on Safari, and later try to create a simple app with a web view - that *should* work, if I [register a custom URL](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1), too.